# Is it possible to correctly disassemble STL inlines?

Tags: ida, decompilation, c++

Is it possible to correctly disassemble STL inlines with IDA? STL inlines are not detected by *FLAIR* just because they are inline not functions. For example how can I know that the code I see disassembled was in the original source

```
  std::set<int> myset;
  myset.insert(10);
```

but not

```
  std::vector<short> myvector;
  myvector.push_back(10);
```

Is it possible somehow to know what the code exactly means when it was originally born?